# Attempting to create anova table with unequal sizes R

Tags: r, sample, anova

I have a bit of an issue with using R. We are trying to create an anova table with unequal amount of sample sizes. I was basing it off an example, however when trying to create it I get an error stating there is a differing number of rows. How would I go about fixing this? Here is the code

```
strokeTable<-data.frame(Strokes=c(sumStroke,shoStroke,winStroke),
            Season=factor(rep(c("Summer Stroke", "Shoulder Stroke", "Winter Stroke", 
            Games=c(length(sumStroke), length(shoStroke), length(winStroke))))))
```

and here's the values

```
sumStroke<-c(83,85,85,87,90,88,88,84,91,90)
shoStroke<-c(91,87,84,87,85,86,83)
winStroke<-c(94,91,87,85,87,91,92,86)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  R got confused because you called your `times` argument (how many times to repeat each factor level) `Games` instead.  The second argument doesn't *have* to be named (R will do *positional matching* in that case), but if it is named it should be called `times` and not anything else ...

```
 strokeTable<-data.frame(Strokes=c(sumStroke,shoStroke,winStroke),
         Season=factor(rep(c("Summer Stroke",
                    "Shoulder Stroke", "Winter Stroke"),
              c(length(sumStroke), length(shoStroke), length(winStroke)))))
```

Alternatively:

```
 L <- list(sumStroke=sumStroke,shoStroke=shoStroke,winStroke=winStroke)
 data.frame(Strokes=unlist(L),
            Season=factor(rep(names(L),sapply(L,length))))
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't even realize that had to be named times! Thank you so much!